# Autohotkey over Hikvision software

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to click on the iVMS-4200 window with a script made with Autohotkey.

The script works as I have tested it on the browser and it doesn't give me any problems. The thing is that on the mentioned software, the clicks don't work.

This is the script in ahk:

```
MouseMove 500, 300 ; Move mouse to my coor
Send {Click Right} ; First right click
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Trying things, I finally made the script work, running it as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is also facing this problem with Autohotkey, just try to run the script as administrator.